# saving an array in EEPROM

Tags: c, avr

I've a vectorx[8] and I  want to save its value in the EEPROM of an XMEGA for that here is what I've done  ::

```
............................
    int16_t  vec1[8]; 
    int16_t  vec2[8]; 
    int16_t  vec3[8];
    int i =  0, j =1; 
    for ( i =0 ; i<8; i++){ // ini 
       vec1[i] = 23500; 
       vec2[i] = 20000;
       vec3[i] = 20000;
    }


for ( i =0; i<8 ; i++) {
 eeprom_update_word (( uint16_t *)j++, vec1[i]);
 eeprom_update_word (( uint16_t *)j++, vec2[i]);
 eeprom_update_word (( uint16_t *)j++, vec3[i]);
}
```

Now when I try to use the saved values  using this : 
................................

```
int16_t tempX[8];
int j  =2 ;
for ( i = 0 ; i < NUMBEROFSENSORS ; i++ ){

        tempX[i] = (int16_t) eeprom_read_word(j);
        j=  j+3;  // reading only vec1 
        printf(" j  read Value is : %d  \n",(int16_t)tempX[i]);
    }
```

I get `-13158` instead of `23500` , so my question is what I doing wrong here ?

âfter changing K  to a point I  I get this  output  :

```
read Value is : 2627
```

read Value is : 2714 
read Value is : 2714 
read Value is : 2714 
read Value is : 23450
read Value is : -3584
read Value is : 31744
read Value is : 11008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `j` as `uint16_t * j`. Then `++` operation will increase it properly with 2 and not 1. And you will not need casting: `eeprom_update_word (j++, vec1[i])`.

Comment: thanks for your help ,but it didn't sovle the problen I stil get weird values.  !